# Web Assembly application not refreshing until hours after restart

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

This happens to me from time to time, not very often.  Not sure what to even search for and wondering if anybody knows the cause.

Every once in a while I will make a change and get an error.  Yesterday it happened twice and both times when calling a Web API nothing happens.  Just doesn't make the call, no error, etc..  I spend quite a bit of time manually verifying that everything looks ok, but continue to get the error.  I try:

1. Hard re-starting the browser and clearing the cache.  Still have the problem.
2. Restart Visual Studio 2022.  Still have the problem.
3. Restart the laptop.  Still have the problem.

After spending a considerable amount of time working on this, will shut the laptop down and go away for a couple of hours.  When I re-start, the code works as expected and I am not able to re-produce the problem.

It happens so infrequently that I am not positive what the circumstances are.  Yesterday, I was working with Web API controllers and this may or may not always be the circumstances.

While it is infrequent, when it happens I can easily lose 1/2 a day with investigation.

Any ideas on what causes this or how I can quickly resolve it?

Comment: Could you provide the minial codes/enviroment that may reproduce the error ?

Comment: Thanks Ruikai. Since I don't know what causes the error, I can't provide a minimal code base (which I know doesn't help); I am unable to reproduce the error, although I expect it to appear again at some point.  

My environment is Win 11 (up to date) /VS 2022 (up to date)/ Sql Server v15.0.4236.7.  I building a Web Assembly application.